# Discord OAuth does not complete only sometimes

Tags: node.js, passport.js, discord.js

```
import passportDiscord from "passport-discord";

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) { done(null, user); });
passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) { done(null, user); });
passport.use(new DiscordStrategy({
    clientID: OAuth.Discord.Client,
    clientSecret: OAuth.Discord.Secret,
    callbackURL: OAuth.Discord.Callback,
    scope: ['identify', 'email']
 },
 function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    const avatarUrl = `https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/${profile.id}/${profile.avatar}.png`;
    User.findOrCreate({ userAuthName: 'Discord', userAuthId: profile.id, userName: profile.username, userEmail: profile.email, userEnum: '0001', userAvatar: avatarUrl  }, function(err, user) {
       process.nextTick(function() {
           return cb(err, user);
       });
    });
 }));

auth.get('/discord', passport.authenticate('discord'));
auth.get('/discord/callback', passport.authenticate('discord', {
    failureRedirect: '/'
}), function (req: any, res: any) {
    User.addLog(req.user.userUniqueId, 'logged_in', Host.getAddress(req));
    let token = User.createJWT(req.user);
    res.cookie('token', token, {maxAge: Core.JWT.expiryMax, domain: Core.cookieUrl})
    res.cookie('world', req.user.userWorld, { domain: Core.cookieUrl });
    res.end();
    return res.redirect(Core.webProtocol + "://" + Core.webUrl)
});
```

This is my Discord Strategy, the `clientID`, `clientSecret` and `callbackURL` are double checked and are valid. They work on Google Chrome but some issues have a 50% success rate on Firefox. Node doesn't return an error log except if the user refresh it will say `invalid code request` which makes sense since the code request won't be valid if you try to use it again.

Edit: I attempted removing `process.nextTick()` and same issue still persists. I also tried disabling Cloudflare and using normal HTTP ports and still same issue persists.

Edit: I'm still struggling even attempting to `npm uninstall passport passport-discord` and re-installing but issue still persists. This includes the one package that has been a commonly known problem with passport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 11 days of struggling on this issue, the solution is

1. Do not use `res.end()` before `return res.redirect()` which sounds obvious now but I was too clueless to notice.
2. Instead of using `res.redirect()` we manually wrote headers using `301`

```
    auth.get('/discord', passport.authenticate('discord'));
    auth.get('/discord/callback', passport.authenticate('discord', {
        failureRedirect: '/'
    }), function (req: any, res: any) {
        User.addLog(req.user.userUniqueId, 'logged_in', Host.getAddress(req));
        let token = User.createJWT(req.user);
        res.cookie('token', token, {maxAge: Core.JWT.expiryMax, domain: Core.cookieUrl})
        res.cookie('world', req.user.userWorld, { domain: Core.cookieUrl });
        res.writeHead(301, { Location: Core.webProtocol + '://' + Core.webUrl });
        res.end();
    });
```